# Referencing Android Library Project Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having issues getting my project that references an Android Library to compile.  I have exactly followed the instructions in the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

My android library is is marked as a library correctly, and I can see the jar file and all my .class files in my project.  But the classes are not found when I try to reference them in my new project and it will not compile.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot (SoundGraphingLibrary is my library project and SoundGraphingLibrary is the project I need to use the library in):

[image]

Comment: sometimes when adding a library, I have found it necessary to run `Project->Clean` on both the library and the referencing project.

Comment: thanks, I had tried that a couple times, still no good

Comment: May be your imports are wrong, try to delete all your import statements and press `Ctrl+Shift+O` to re-import files that you need.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, too. Any chance the `(default package)` designation on your library is causing issues? You might try refactoring that to something more standard.

Comment: Yeah I had the same thought after posting this, no luck, but thanks

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the project and the library project are in the same folder..

Answer (score 1):

First, run `Project->Clean` on the library, then your project as @iagreen suggests.  Then go ahead and close and reopen eclipse.  Wait for everything to build.

Assuming nothing is better at this point, click on the library and do `Project->Properties->Android`. Confirm that `Is Library` is checked. Now, delete any instance of the library *.jar in your project. Do `Project->Properties->Android` on your project. Click `Add...` and click on the library you want, `OK`, `Apply`, `OK`.

That should do it. Also, fire lemurs.

Comment: yeah thanks for the try, I had done this stuff several times, no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but i did the following

- Remove and adding the library by going to Project->Properties->Android.
- Clear the project by going to Project->Clean
- Restart Eclipse and tata it works.